# Galois correspondence in infinite extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Definition of Galois extension**: An extension $K$ of $F$ will be called Galois, if **it is algebraic** (edited after comment by Thorgott) and the fixed subfield under all $F$-automorphisms of $K$ is precisely $F$.

Let $L/k$ be Galois.

For $k\subset M\subset L$ (intermediate subfield), $L/M$ is Galois and  ${\rm Gal}(L/M)$ is subgroup of ${\rm Gal}(L/k)$.

**Claim:** The association $M\mapsto {\rm Gal}(L/M)$ is one-one i.e. injective (even if $[L:k]$ is infinite).

**Justification:** If $\mathcal{M}$ is the collection of subfields of $L$ (containing $k$) and $\mathcal{H}$ is the collection of subgroups of ${\rm Gal}(L/k)$, then we have mappings between them as:
$$
M\mapsto {\rm Gal}(L/M) \,\,\,\,\, and \,\,\,\, H\mapsto L^H=\mbox{subfield of L fixed by H }
$$
Given $M\in\mathcal{M}$, the subfield of $L$ fixed under ${\rm Gal}(L/M)$ contains $M$, but it is exactly $M$ since $L$ is Galois over $M$. This means the composition
$$
M\mapsto {\rm Gal}(L/M)\mapsto L^{{\rm Gal}(L/M)}
$$
is identity, hence passing from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{H}$ in natural way is always $1-1$ map.

**Question:** Is the above claim with justification correct? (If not, what corrections should I do? I did not find mention of simple remark in books, so worried of above thought.)

---

Comment: I do not believe your definition of a Galois extension is correct in the infinite case, it doesn't even force $K/F$ to be algebraic, which you should want. For example, let $F$ be an infinite field of characteristic $2$. The extension $F(X)/F$ is Galois in your sense (if $p$ is a non-constant polynomial, there is $t\in F$, such that $p(t)\neq p(0)$, since $F$ is infinite, and then the automorphism $X\mapsto X+t$ moves $p$), but $F(X)/F(X^2)$ is purely inseparable, so not Galois in your sense. Thus, your association is actually not well-defined.

Comment: @Sorry; I forgot to mention algebraic extension.

Comment: The property is incorrect for infinite extensions. The issue is a rather subtle one: since infinite subextensions are “made up with” (formally, colimits of) finite subextensions, it stands to reason that their Galois group has to satisfy some sort of “limit of finite”-ness property. Formally, the infinit Galois group is endowed with a topology (the *Krull topology*) for which it is profinite, and the correspondence maps bijectively subextensions to *closed* subgroups.

Comment: With the algebraicity assumption, this is correct, and your argument is too, but of course the actual heart of the argument is the proof that $L/K$ Galois => $L/M$ Galois in the first place.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 1-1 here. For example, there can be many subgroups $G$ of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$ such that $L^G = M$. The map $M\mapsto \mathrm{Gal}(L/M)$ from subfields of $L$ to subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$ is not surjective. Its image is the closed subgroups of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$ in the profinite topology.